# C++ equivalent of Python's scipy.sparse.rand

Tags: c++, scipy, stl, sparse-matrix

I need C++ equivalent of Python's `scipy.sparse.rand` function (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.rand.html). I will input `m, n, density` parameters and `rand()` function will generate a matrix (preferably COO  matrix) for me. How can I do it?

Comment: The C++ standard library doesn't have matrix facilities. Do you have in mind a library that you want to use, or do you want us to recommend one? Software recommendations (including libraries) are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `boost` on your hands it might be a good idea to use a combination of [boost-ublas](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.html) and [boost-random](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) to do the job. 
For this you have to install the [boost](https://www.boost.org/) libraries beforehand.

You might optimize the code if you know beforehand the number of non-zero elements.

You can watch the code work at:
https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/097ea92bb336c774

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix_sparse.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_01.hpp>

int main() {
    int rows{ 4 };
    int cols{ 4 };
    double density{ 0.25 };
    boost::random::uniform_01<> dist;
    boost::random::mt19937 gen;

    boost::numeric::ublas::mapped_matrix<double> m(rows, cols, 3 * 3);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < m.size1(); ++i)
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < m.size2(); ++j)
            if (dist(gen)>density) m(i, j) = dist(gen);

    std::cout << m << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do not understand your code. Please check the example in (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.rand.html). The example is creating a 3 by 4 matrix, where density is 0.25. The 3 by 4 matrix contains 12 (3*4) elements. The density 0.25 means. Out of 12 elements, 3 (12*0.25) elements will be non-zero and others will be zero. I ran your code. It is not create something like this. Please let me know I can I replicate the example provided in the following link (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.rand.html)

Comment: @BeautifulMind: I updated the question. Please check the link above to see the code at work.

Comment: I know it is working, but it is not providing the correct answer. Your code generates 10 non-zero elements and 6 zero elements. However, it should generate 12 zero elements (for 4 by 4 matrix - 4*4 elements) and 4 (16*0.25 = 4 ) non-zero elements. Please check the python [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.rand.html) that I provided. It has an example for 3 by 4 matrix.